# How to use dart-protobuf

Tags: dart, protocol-buffers

I'm considering using [dart-protobuf](https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-protobuf) instead of JSON in one of my projects. The problem is that the library does not provide any example of how to use it, and the tests don't really help either.

I'm also a bit confused on how the parsing of `.proto` files would work.

So I'm looking for a simple example of how to use this library in dart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with dart-protobuf, but it looks like you have to use the protobuf compiler and the dart-protoc-plugin project to generate your Dart protobuf library from a proto definition.

There are some instructions here:
https://github.com/dart-lang/dart-protoc-plugin

Comment: Thank you! I just figured it out this second. The description: »Typically one do not need to import this library---only libraries generated by protoc plugin import this library directly.« was a bit confusing, because I didn't really get that I had to generate libraries myself.

Answer (score 7):

I use it and it's awesome.
Below the part that was the hardest for me (de/serialization). Maybe docs are better now.

send request (`query` is the protocol buffer object to send)

```
request.send(query.writeToBuffer());
```

receive response (`pb.MovieMessage` is the protocol buffer object to deserialize the response to)

```
request.onLoad.listen((ProgressEvent e) {
  if ((request.status >= 200 && request.status < 300) ||
      request.status == 0 || request.status == 304) {

    List<int> buffer = new Uint8List.view(request.response);
    var response = new pb.MovieMessage.fromBuffer(buffer);
```

**EDIT**

My method to send a PB request to the server

```
Future<pb.MovieMessage> send(pb.MovieMessage query) {

  var completer = new Completer<pb.MovieMessage>();
  var uri = Uri.parse("http://localhost:8080/public/data/");

  var request = new HttpRequest()
  ..open("POST", uri.toString(), async: true)
    ..overrideMimeType("application/x-google-protobuf")
    ..setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/x-google-protobuf")
    ..setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-google-protobuf")
    ..responseType = "arraybuffer"
    ..withCredentials = true // seems to be necessary so that cookies are sent
    ..onError.listen((e) {
      completer.completeError(e);
    })
    ..onProgress.listen((e){},
        onError:(e) => _logger.severe("Error: " + e.errorMessage));

    request.onReadyStateChange.listen((e){},
        onError: (e) => _logger.severe("OnReadyStateChange.OnError: " + e.toString())
        );

    request.onLoad.listen((ProgressEvent e) {
      if ((request.status >= 200 && request.status < 300) ||
          request.status == 0 || request.status == 304) {

        List<int> buffer = new Uint8List.view(request.response);
        var response = new pb.MovieMessage.fromBuffer(buffer);
        response.errors.forEach((pb.Error e) => _logger.severe("Error: " + e.errorMessage));

        completer.complete(response);
      } else {
        completer.completeError(e);
      }
    });

    request.send(query.writeToBuffer()); 
    return completer.future;
  }
```

Comment: How did you create the initial request?

Comment: I'm not sure what you need. I added some more code. If you explain what you already achieved and where you're stuck it's probably easier to help.