# Dart BrowserClient POST not including my cookies

Tags: cookies, dart, cors, dartium

I'm doing a BrowserClient POST across domains and don't see my cookies being included.

This the response I'm getting:

[image]

When I send another POST request, I don't see the cookies being included:

[image]

Going straight to the test page, I can see the cookies being included:

[image]
[image]

The Dart code I use to make a POST:

```
var client = new BrowserClient();

client.post(url, body: request, headers:{"Content-Type" : "application/json", "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials":"true"}).then((res) {
      if (res.statusCode == 200) {
        var response = JSON.decode(res.body);

        callback(response);
      } else {
        print(res.body);
        print(res.reasonPhrase);
      }
    }).whenComplete(() {
      client.close();
    });
```

Not sure about the Access-Control-Allow-Credentials header I'm including, with or without it, nothing changes.

Am I missing headers on the server side that needs to be set on the response or is Dartium blocking cross-domain cookies?

More details on [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/84860/how-to-build-a-secure-stateless-authentication-system-for-a-client-side-javascri?noredirect=1#comment141033_84860) and the reasoning behind setting cookies via the server.

Update: Enhancement request logged: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=23088

Update: Enhancement implemented, one should now be able to do `var client = new BrowserClient()..withCredentials=true;` based on 
https://github.com/dart-lang/http/commit/9d76e5e3c08e526b12d545517860c092e089a313

Comment: I guess you need to set `withCredentials=true` on your post request, but I haven't found yet how to do this with the request from the http package (like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21770445 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16939328).

Comment: I can see special provision being made for that in angular.dart, but not in BrowserClient https://github.com/dsalsbury/angular.dart/commit/9ff1bc321cd201bee09f8420c42e61632481ffb7

Comment: If angular.dart is doing it, surely it must be calling standard dart libraries under the hood or does angular.dart have its own BrowserClient-like library?

Comment: No, in browser you can't do HTTP requests other than using the HttpRequest API from dart:html. Angular and browserClient just forward to it. The http package was created to have an unified API between client and server. On the server it forwards to dart:io and on the browser on dart:html.

Comment: Is it possible to do HTTP requests directly to the HttpRequest API in dart:html thereby doing my own BrowserClient implementation?
Otherwise, should I log a feature request for withCredentials on the BrowserClient package?

Comment: Sure, no need to use the http package. This is mostly for convenience for code which targets client and server. Yes, please create a bug report/feature request at http://dartbug.com.

Comment: I've logged an enhancement request: https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=23088
 In the meantime I'll go a bit lower level and just use HttpRequest directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For cookies being sent to CORS requests, you need to set `withCredentials = true`. The browser client in the `http` package doesn't support this argument. You can use the `HttpRequest` from `dart:html` instead.
See [How to use dart-protobuf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21770445) for an example.

Comment: A pull-request with a fix for the http package was already made. Hopefully published soon.

Comment: I can see the fix on Github, what is the usual timespan for fixes to be published? If it's around a week, I'll wait a bit, otherwise I'll follow the dart-protobuf example so that I can at least finish my authentication layer.

Comment: According to the changelog on pub.dartlang.org a release containing this change was released two days ago.

Comment: You can just update the package not the entire Dart installation. Just run `pub upgrade` on command line from within your package directory or from the context menu of the `pubspec.yaml` file in DartEditor.